# FabricJS Alternating between canvas elements?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Let's say I have two canvas elements:

```js
<canvas id="c1" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
<canvas id="c2" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
<canvas id="c3" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

From looking at the docs, it tells me that I can use this to convert the canvas into a FabricJS canvas.

```
var c = new fabric.Canvas('c1', {
    preserveObjectStacking: true,
    isDrawingMode: false
});
```

Now, if I wanted to do something with this new canvas, adding a circle for instance, I could use this function:

```js
function AddCircle() {
  var object = new fabric.Circle({
      radius: 15,
      fill: 'blue',
      left: 100,
      top: 100
  });
  c.add(object);
}
```

Now, this is all well and good for `c1` but `c2` and `c3` won't do anything because it's never being initialized. So is it possible to alternate between FabricJS canvas elements?

I'd like the functionality to be similar to `activeCanvas.add(object)` instead of just `c.add(object)`.

Before you respond, please note that I'm well aware that I could just use the same method for the `c2` element, but I'd like to alternate between canvas elements instead as I have something planned for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by alternating between canvas elements, but here's my recommendation.

Initialize all canvases first:

```
var options = { preserveObjectStacking: true, isDrawingMode: false };
var c1 = new fabric.Canvas('c1', options),
    c2 = new fabric.Canvas('c2', options),
    c3 = new fabric.Canvas('c3', options);
```

Reference the appropriate canvas when performing a Fabric actions:

```
c1.add(object1);
c2.add(object2);
c3.add(object3);
```

FabricJS doesn't have an inbuilt activeCanvas variable when working with multiple canvases, but you can achieve that using events.

```
//declare global activeCanvas variable and allCanvas array
var activeCanvas,
    allCanvas = [c1,c2,c3];

//create function for updating activeCanvas variable
function setActiveCanvas(canvas) {
   activeCanvas = canvas;
}

//adds event to each canvas to update the activeCanvas variable when the mouse enters any canvas
allCanvas.forEach(function(item,index){
    item.on('mouse:over', setActiveCanvas(this));
});
```

Now your activeCanvas variable will always refer to the last canvas your mouse entered. Obviously using the `mouse:over` event won't work if you want to support touch devices so you may want to choose [another event](http://fabricjs.com/events) that best fits your project.

Now you can modify your `AddCircle()` function to refer to the activeCanvas.

```
function AddCircle() {
  var object = new fabric.Circle({
      radius: 15,
      fill: 'blue',
      left: 100,
      top: 100
  });
  activeCanvas.add(object);
}
```

Comment: @Venk if this answers your question please mark as accepted so that the bounty is not lost.

Comment: Hello, unfortunately this is not what I wanted as I knew how to do this already. Note the last section of my post.

Comment: Hi, feel free to update your question to clarify what you're looking for then and I will try to help

Answer (score 0):

[Melciar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66204075/5243309)'s answer is a fantastic explanation, and I recommend you read it, but I'd like to build on one thing he said. You can initialize them like this:

```
var options = { preserveObjectStacking: true, isDrawingMode: false };
var c1 = new fabric.Canvas('c1', options),
    c2 = new fabric.Canvas('c2', options),
    c3 = new fabric.Canvas('c3', options),
    allCanvas = [c1, c2, c3];
```

And now you can modify them all, or individually. If you want to modify them all simultaniously, you can do this:

```
allCanvas.forEach(function(item,index){
      var myCircle = new fabric.Circle({
          radius: 15,
          fill: 'blue',
          left: 100,
          top: 100
      });
      item.add(myCircle);
});
```

and, of course, you can still modify them individually as per [melchair](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66204075/5243309)'s fantastic explanation:

```
c1.add(object1);
c2.add(object2);
c3.add(object3);
```

Comment: Nice idea storing the list of canvases in an array. It definitely makes the code for initializing the same event for all canvases much cleaner. I only removed your suggestion for adding a circle to all canvas within a forEach loop from my answer since the issue didn't expressly ask for that.